# How to safely use PayPal IPN with Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, paypal-ipn

Here are two sources for PayPal IPN:

- [Kona.Web IPN](https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Kona.Web/Controllers/PayPalController.cs)
- [DotNetNuke IPN](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/50693#545460)

DNN has a loop in the beginning of the Page_Load method that captures txn_type and txn_id, which I don't see in the Kona code.
DNN also captures payer email and other information into local variables.
I am trying to make sure that I incorporate some of the security checks that I see in DNN into my MVC IPN.

How do I do what DNN is doing with MVC 2 with Kona as the base?
Is the Kona.Web IPN safe for production, does it need some more tweaking?

Comment: I believe the loop at the beginning of the Page_Load is just a way to iterate through the variables and identity the ones you want to use and validate against it. You could alternative do custom = Request["custom"] instead of the for loop for the variables you want. The key in the security is that the values Paypal posted to you is kept intact and haven't been tampered with. This is why you post back the exact string back to Paypal.